# react-native bluetooth connection with Accu-check Guide-me

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth

I am developing an app that works with various health measuring bluetooth devices.

I am using with React-native and react-native-ble-plx.

I don't know much about Bluetooth, so I'm searching each device and developing it.

Some sphygmomanometers and scales have completed, but the blood glucose meter, which requires input of a serial number, cannot be linked.

The connection Bluetooth that has been developed so far is as follows.

Scan -> Found device -> Stop scan -> Connect -> discover all services&characteristics -> Find service list -> filter measurement service -> find characteristics list from filtered service -> monitor those

The device I am having a hard time developing right now is the “Accu-check Guide Me” blood glucose device.

Other devices are receiving the measured values ​​well.

But after this device is connected, if the test strip is inserted into the machine, the Bluetooth connection is cut off.

Connect -> Popup to insert serial number -> insert serial number -> connected success -> insert test strip into Accu-check -> disconnected

Perhaps unlike other devices, this device seems to have to do something more in between the normal flow, but it is difficult to find out from my knowledge even if I search hard.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what more to do in the code below.

```js
const scanAndConnectAcucheckGlucoseMeter = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = 0;
    console.log('scanStart');
    manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error : ' + error);
        return;
      }

      const deviceName = device.name;
      if (deviceName != null) {
        if (deviceName.includes('meter+')) {
          console.log('detected!!');
          manager.stopDeviceScan();
          resolve(device);
        }
      }
    });
  });
};


const MonitoringForAcucheckGuideMe = device => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    device
      .connect()
      .then(device => {
        const result = device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
        return result;
      })
      .then(device => {
        return device.services();
      })
      .then(services => {
        // 180A : device information
        // 1800 : generic access
        // 1808 : glucose
        // 00000000-0000-1000-1000-00000000000 : custom service
        const result = services.filter(id => id.uuid.indexOf('1808') != -1); // Glucose Service
        return result[0].characteristics();
      })
      .then(characters => {
        // Glucose Measurement :00002A18 / Descriptors 2902
        // Glucose Feature : 2A51
        // Record Access Control Point 2A52 / Descriptors 2902
        // DateTime 2A08
        const glucoseMeasurement = characters.filter(
          data => data.uuid.indexOf('2a18') != -1, // 2a35 is for blood sugar measurement
        );

        // popup to insert pin number on mobile when monitor()
        glucoseMeasurement[0].monitor((error, characteristic) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log('error:::::', error);
            reject(error);
          }
          
          const Valuebytes = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, 'base64');
          
          console.log(Valuebytes);

          const result = "Not yet"
          resolve(result)
          
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same with this exact version of Glucometer. How did you end up going with this issue. I can see the same thing happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Apart from the fact that your 'answer' doesn't answer the question (which suggests that a visit to the [tour] would be a good place for you to start), have you checked that your device might implement the interface as [officially documented](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/#post-87028)?

Comment: This would be better as a comment on the question rather than an answer.

Comment: @risto Thanks for getting back. I tried to find interface details for this specific device, and I couldn't get any info on it. But through debugging I can see they are doing some funny logic with send the glucose details up to other device as there is an almost 10 - 15 sec timer before the connection is auto closed by the glucometer.

Comment: Apologies for replying as an answer. I created an account to comment, but there was a warning that said I needed 50 rep to comment, but I really needed a way to get in touch with the OP to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some people are still curious about this topic, even though quite some time has passed since I posted my question. My memory is a bit hazy due to the time lapse, but what I recall distinctly is that the timing for connecting the device via Bluetooth was different than expected.
For example, instead of establishing the Bluetooth connection in advance and then inserting the strip for measurement, the process was to measure the blood sugar first and then immediately after removing the strip, proceed with Scan -> Connect.

Another point was that the glucose meter stores the measurement data on the device itself, so it's not about immediately transferring data upon measuring. Instead, the method involves periodically attempting to connect using the device ID to retrieve past stored data.

I was successful with both methods, and all of these procedures were carried out after finalizing an agreement with the glucose meter manufacturer and regarding Bluetooth integration.